# Changing Size of Squares in forest plot R

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I'm new to R and am making some forest plots.  I have figured out how to make them using the following code:

```
library(forestplot)
library(rmeta)

jpeg("test21.jpeg", units = "in", width = 7, height = 7, res = 100)

forestplot(tabletext2, 
        mean = for_forest$median, lower = for_forest$lower, upper = for_forest$upper,
           xlog = FALSE,
        clip = c(-0.006,0.002),
        xticks = c(-0.0006,-0.0004,-0.0002,0,0.0002),
        zero = 0,
           col = fpColors(box = "royalblue",
                          line = "darkblue",
                          summary = "royalblue"))



dev.off()
```

And I get a decent looking output:

[image]

But how do I make the boxes that represent the median all the same size?  It seems that more negative medians are smaller boxes while less negative medians are bigger boxes.  So the magnitude of the median is represented 2 ways, with the position along the line and with its size which is somewhat confusing.

Also how would I make the lines thicker?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should provide enough data to create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we can debug.

However, looking at the [Package Documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forestplot/forestplot.pdf) it says that the boxsize is based on precision, and can be overwritten using the `boxsize` argument. Without sample data to test, I can only give a possible answer, but looking at the examples in the documentation, try adding `boxsize = 0.25`

Also there, it says the line widths are set in `shapes_gp`. So try adding `shapes_gp = fpShapesGp(default = gpar(lwd = 3))`

```
forestplot(tabletext2, 
           mean = for_forest$median, lower = for_forest$lower, upper = for_forest$upper,
           xlog = FALSE,
           clip = c(-0.006,0.002),
           xticks = c(-0.0006,-0.0004,-0.0002,0,0.0002),
           zero = 0,
           col = fpColors(box = "royalblue",
                          line = "darkblue",
                          summary = "royalblue"),
           boxsize = 0.25,
           shapes_gp = fpShapesGp(default = gpar(lwd = 3)))
```

If this doesn't work please send some data for a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I can debug here.

Comment: Thank you, the boxsize argument allowed me to specify a size for all boxes.  The shapes_gp line did not change the line thickness, but I'll try some other commands and research that further as this is a secondary issue for me.

Comment: Oh well, you win some you lose some . There are other examples in the documentation setting the `shapes_gp` you could try. Or you could google `fpShapesGp()` or `gpar()`, as these are what forestplot uses. Good luck!

Comment: Try `shapes_gp = fpShapesGp(lines = gpar(lwd = 3))` or `shapes_gp = fpShapesGp(lines = gpar(lwd = 6))`

Comment: Hmm still no effect, good to know about the shapes_gp documentation.  Definitely something I'll have to read up on.  Thanks!